# How to execute a javascript function when a specific Primefaces p:tab is selected

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I need to execute a javascript function when a p:tab in a p:tabView is selected. I don't need any  backend method, but just a simple javascript function executed. i have tried adding "onclick" to the p:tab tag but that won't work.

I can always execute a backend bean method and execute javascript there using requestContext.execute() but seems odd.

Thanks

Comment: Try an `console.log(event)`, or `console.log(this)` and check what is all available with a browser developer tool. If yo you do not need to call a server side method at all, you can always use [`pe:javascript`](http://primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/clientBehaviours/javascriptBehaviour.jsf) from PrimeFaces extensions

Comment: And you can also check the client-side api, `tabWidget.getActiveIndex()` (given the widgetVar of the tabView is 'tabWidget`) and backwards
Compatibility is on, otherwise it would be `PF('tabWidget').getActiveIndex()`

Answer (score 2):

Like @Kukeltje said, you can access the Primefaces `tabView` component through the `widgetVar` attribute on the client-side. It can be accessed in javascript calling `PF('yourWidgetVar')` (since version 5.x) or simply calling `yourWidgetVar` (version 4.x and prior, see https://code.google.com/archive/p/primefaces/wikis/MigrationGuide.wiki).

The **client-side widget API** and the **client-side callbacks** are described in Primefaces User Guide (http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_0.pdf).

**Example using client-side API**

There is a client-side function called `getActiveIndex()`, which returns the index of the currently active Tab (the counting starts from `0`).
In the example the `alert` is shown only on the 2nd tab:

```
<h:form>
    <p:tabView widgetVar="varTabView">
        <p:ajax event="tabChange" oncomplete="if (PF('varTabView').getActiveIndex() == 1) alert ('the 2nd tab');" />
        <p:tab title="Tab1" id="tab1">
            <h:outputText value="Tab1 content"/>
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab title="Tab2" id="tab2">
            <h:outputText value="Tab2 content"/>
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
</h:form>
```

**Example using client-side callbacks**

You could also use the `onTabChange` attribute/callback on `tabView`:

Javascript callback:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleTabChange(selectedIndex) {
        alert("selected tab: " + selectedIndex);
    }
</script>
```

Page:

```
<h:form>
    <p:tabView onTabChange="handleTabChange(index)">
        <p:tab title="Tab1">
            <h:outputText value="Tab1 content"/>
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab title="Tab2">
            <h:outputText value="Tab2 content"/>
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
</h:form>
```